# Linux mint hangs on power off but not on reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Power off hangs on UI power off or using poweroff command. However reboot command works fine.

I am not using any proprietary driver.

[Thinkpenguin Galapagos Penguin GNU/Linux Laptop](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/galapagos-penguin-gnulinux-laptop)

Linux Mint 18 - 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

systemctl --version output:

> systemd 229
>   +PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN

The rest of the log looks like everything is fine but it is not powering off.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the BIOS configuration. I cannot say exactly what was the error but it is working after setting it to optimized defaults.